# Asynchronous file upload in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing an application in Spring MVC which has a file upload functionality. I have seen a lot of answers regarding async file upload most of which are using ajax. I would like to know if it is possible for the user to navigate through the site while the file is being uploaded.

The uploadform is the input element I am tried to turn into a file uploader. This works fine, but the problem is the process doesn't run in the background. So if I navigate from the page, the upload is interrupted. Any directions regarding this is appreciated.

```
$("#uploadform").ajaxForm({
  beforeSend: function() {
      $("#progressBar").show();
      $("#status").html('');
      $("#progressBar").jqxProgressBar({ value:1 });
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        if(percentComplete<90)
        $("#progressBar").jqxProgressBar({ value:percentComplete });
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("response "+response);
        responseAjax=response;
        $("#progressBar").jqxProgressBar({ value:95 });
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        $("#progressBar").jqxProgressBar({ value:100 });
        if(responseAjax.indexOf('Success') !=-1)
            $("#status").css('color','green');
        else
            $("#status").css('color','red');
        $("#status").html(responseAjax);            
        //alert("Upload complete");
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Just FYI -> `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry about the generic question. This is my first. I have added the code that I am trying to use above. Hope that helps.